# With ECDSA is there a way for the verifier to calculate any properties of $k$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa, zero-knowledge-proofs

With ECDSA, given $(r,s)$ and $m$, is there a way for a verifier to calculate any (boolean) properties of $k$, without knowing $k$ or the private key $D_A$?

(I understand that $k$ should be random, or follow RFC6979, but I'm curious.)

In particular, could the verifier compute, given a signature $(r,s)$ and a message $m$, that:

1. $k$ is odd
2. $k$ has some mathematical relation to one of the curve parameters
3. $k$ has some mathematical relation to the public key $Q_A$
4. $k$ has some mathematical relation to the (truncated) message hash $z$
5. $k$ was deterministically generated with RFC6979. See the article [*Android Security Vulnerability*](https://bitcoin.org/en/alert/2013-08-11-android) for the value of $k$ which was used to generate the signature.

(Variable names were taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm).)

Comment: By $K$, do you mean $k$ (as in the article)?

Comment: Also, to whom should this be proven? By itself, the statement "$k$ is odd" is meaningless since $k$ is not defined. However, given a signature $(r,s)$ and a message $m$, the statement "the value of $k$ which was used to generate this signature is odd" may be meaningful, assuming there is only one possible $k$, or all the possible $k$s have the same parity.

Comment: Yes, I've corrected my question.  How did you write the pretty-k in your comment?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the explicit information about the signature and message.

Comment: See [this help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math.SE about TeX formatting.

Comment: Isn't it the signer which should prove this? Since it's the signer who is supposed to know $k$.

Comment: Yes, the signer does know $k$ and the verifier doesn't.  I want the verifier to be able to prove that the signer is sticking to RFC6979 or similar and I'm curious as to what else the verifier could prove about $k$.

Comment: I think you may be using the word "to prove" in a different way than it is normally used in cryptography. Do you actually mean "it is possible to compute/obtain the parity of $k$ from $(r,s)$ and $m$"?

Comment: Amended, yes the word was misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no relation we are currently aware of.
The reason is as follows. The map
$$k \mapsto (k G).x$$ is assumed to be a good pseudo random number generator.
(The NSA infiltration of the Dual EC drgb has nothing to do with that fact).
This basically says that k and r can be seen as independant random variables.